# show annihilator space is subspace of another annihilator space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let U and V be subspace of a finite-dimensional linear space X. Prove:

If $U \subset V$, then $V^0 \subset U^0$.

This doesn't seem right, at least i'm not sure how to approach it.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f \in V^{\circ}$. Then $f(v) = 0 \quad \forall v \in V$. Since $U \subset V$ it follows that$f(u) = 0 \quad \forall u \in U$, i.e. $f \in U^{\circ}$.